# What is the "successive-configuration relation"?

Tags: complexity

This term is used in the book Foundations of Cryptography on pg 20 with regard to defining deterministic oracles, but is not previously defined and I can't seem to find a definition online easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's first observe the usage of the word in-context:

> **Definition 1.3.8 (Oracle Machines):** A (deterministic/probabilistic)
>   **oracle machine** is a (deterministic/probabilistic) Turing machine with
>   an additional tape, called the **oracle tape**, and two special states,
>   called **oracle invocation** and **oracle appeared**. **The computation of the
>   deterministic oracle machine $M$ on input $x$ and with access to the
>   oracle** $f:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^*$ is defined by the
>   **successive-configuration relation**. For configurations with states
>   different from oracle invocation, the next configuration is defined as
>   usual. Let $\gamma$ be a configuration in which the state is oracle
>   invocation and the content of the oracle tape is $q$. Then the
>   configuration following $\gamma$ is identical to $\gamma$ , except that the state is
>   oracle appeared, and the content of the oracle tape is $f(q)$. The
>   string $q$ is called $M$’s **query**, and $f(q)$ is called the **oracle reply**.
>   The computation of a probabilistic oracle machine is defined
>   analogously. The output distribution of the oracle machine $M$, on input
>   $x$ and with access to the oracle $f$ , is denoted $M^f(x)$.

So the context we have is: [Turing Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)!

Now if we look at the [formal definition of a turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition), we will spot a relation $\delta:(Q\setminus F)\times\Gamma\to Q\times \Gamma\times\{L,R\}$. [Note how a function is actually just a relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition).

This above function defines, when in a given state and looking at a given cell content, which cell content shall be written, where state shall be entered and which direction the head shall be moved. Thus, this relation defines the *successive configuration* for every configuration. However I'd guess that the relation used for the turing machine in question is a little bit more complicated than the one of the "basic" turing macine (also accounting for the special states and the extra tape).